# How to close a popup when marker layer is closed on click using Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am having trouble closing/removing popups when marker layers are closed on click. I have tried to use popup.remove in an onclick function, but haven't had much luck binding the function with the buttons used to show and hide the marker layers. Any help on having popups close when markers layers are closed or hidden would be much appreciated.

**JS:**

```js
    // add popup to layer
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
            layers: ["high_camp"] // Add layers
        });

        if (!features.length) {
            return;
        }

        var feature = features[0];

        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            offset: {
                'top': [0, 0],
                'top-left': [0, 0],
                'top-right': [0, 0],
                'bottom': [0, -40],
                'bottom-left': [0, -40],
                'bottom-right': [0, -40],
                'left': [18, -22],
                'right': [-18, -22],
            }
        })
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML(feature.properties.NAME)
        // Change attribute, properties.'Replace' (Uppercase)
        .addTo(map);
    });

    // Toggle high camp layer
    var togglehighcampId = ["high_camp"]; // Add layer

    document.getElementById("highcampIcon").onclick = function (e) { 
        // Change button name, getElementById('Replace')
        for (var index in togglehighcampId) {
            var clickedLayer = togglehighcampId[index];
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

            if (visibility === 'none') {
                map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
                this.className = '';
            } else {
                this.className = 'on';
                map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: Could you please spell out what you mean by "when marker layers are closed on click"? Are you talking about Marker objects or map layers? And what do you mean "closed on click"?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I have a set of GeoJSON points (icons) that can be toggled on and off using a click function (an html button in this case), and these points have popups that can be closed by either clicking on the map somewhere or on the popup's close button. When the set of points are toggled off, any open popups remain. I am trying to have any open popups close when the points are toggled off when the button is clicked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can keep your popup in global scope to access it in your onclick method

Something like this :

```js
    var popup;

    // add popup to layer
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
            layers: ["high_camp"] // Add layers
        });

        if (!features.length) {
            return;
        }

        var feature = features[0];

        popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            offset: {
                'top': [0, 0],
                'top-left': [0, 0],
                'top-right': [0, 0],
                'bottom': [0, -40],
                'bottom-left': [0, -40],
                'bottom-right': [0, -40],
                'left': [18, -22],
                'right': [-18, -22],
            }
        })
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML(feature.properties.NAME)
        // Change attribute, properties.'Replace' (Uppercase)
        .addTo(map);
    });

    // Toggle high camp layer
    var togglehighcampId = ["high_camp"]; // Add layer

    document.getElementById("highcampIcon").onclick = function (e) { 
        // Change button name, getElementById('Replace')
        for (var index in togglehighcampId) {
            var clickedLayer = togglehighcampId[index];
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

            if (visibility === 'none') {
                map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
                this.className = '';
            } else {
                this.className = 'on';
                popup.remove(); // REMOVE THE POPUP WHEN THE LAYER IS REMOVED
                map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
            }
        }

    };
```

PS: The code is not tested